# Twilio call log API call resource returns blank

Tags: java, eclipse, twilio

```
public void fetchTwilioReport(){
        System.out.println("fetchTwilioReport called");
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID,AUTH_TOKEN);
        ResourceSet<Call> calls = Call.reader().limit(20).read();
        
        for(Call record : calls) {
            System.out.println(record.getSid());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get a list of calls, but the above code returns a blank. I am using twilio 8.11.0.

Comment: What do you mean you are using Twilio 8.11.0 but Twilio-Java-sdk 6.3.0? The latest version of the Twilio Java library is 8.11.0, so if you are using 6.3.0 it is way out of date and likely won’t work.

Comment: Hi I am using twilio 8.11.0 . But the above code does not seem to work . I don't get anything in the console . Its just blank .

Comment: Are there any errors? How are you running it? And how are you injecting the account Sid and auth token into the code?

Comment: I am hard coding the Account Sid and auth token into two variables called ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN. 
I am calling fetchTwilioReport() method on button click .  
No there are no errors.

Comment: On a button click? What kind of app is this?

Comment: I have a button (PrimeFaces) it calls this method on click. I just need to get all call log in a given period . 

```
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
        CallList calls = mainAccount.getCalls();
        for (Call call : calls) {
            System.out.println("From: " + call.getFrom() + " To: " + call.getTo());
        }
``` 

Instead of using Twilio.Init() i tried with above (old way of doing) . It returned all the calls .But filtration is not possible.

Comment: Where did you find this old way of doing it? And are you sure you’re using the latest Twilio Java if old code works and new code doesn’t?

Comment: I found the old way from twilio website itself (used in one old example). Yes the new code does not work . twilio version 8.11.0

Comment: It is really strange to me that the code would do nothing, not throw an error or print the call Sids. When you say the code returns a blank, do you mean nothing is logged? Do you see "fetchTwilioReport called" logged at least?

Comment: Yes i did see "fetchTwilioReport called" after that nothing is logged .

Comment: I'm going to try to get one of my colleagues who understands Java better than I do to take a look. I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Ok.Sure .Thank You very much .

Answer (score 1):

Curious. The code you have posted does fetch a list of calls for me. For clarity, here is a self-contained example of code which prints out 20 call SIDs:

```java
package com.example;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.base.ResourceSet;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;

public class CallReaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(
            System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"),
            System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"));

        ResourceSet<Call> calls = Call.reader().limit(20).read();

        for (Call record : calls) {
            System.out.println(record.getSid());
        }
    }
}
```

As this is in a Maven project, I have imported the Twilio Helper library in `pom.xml` with:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If this code still returns no calls for you, then the next thing I would check is whether there actually are any calls in the account which those credentials access. Possibly "no calls" is the correct answer? You can fetch call data from the API using the same URL that the Java library does:

```
https://${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}:${TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}/Calls.json
```

Replace `${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}` and `${TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN}` with your account credentials in that URL and you can load it with curl or in a web browser. The JSON that is returned will have a key `calls` whose value is a list of objects full of call data.

Then there are two possibilities. If the API is returning calls and the Java Helper isn't giving them to you then we need to dig further into the Java side of things. If there are no calls and you think there definitely should be then we can look more into your account setup and take it from there.  Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Okay . Thank You . I will try it .